# Angular 7 Material autocomplete options not shown

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I'm using the exact code from the [angular page](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview), with the only difference being I'm using Angular 7 and @angular/material 7.

component.html:

```html
<!-- added to see that value is changing -->
<li *ngFor="let street of filteredStreets | async">{{street }}</li> 

<form class="example-form">
    <input type="text"
           matInput
           placeholder="Search for a street"
           [formControl]="control"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let street of filteredStreets | async" [value]="street">
            {{street}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

component.ts:

```js
control = new FormControl();
streets: string[] = ['Champs-Élysées', 'Lombard Street', 'Abbey Road', 'Fifth Avenue'];
filteredStreets: Observable<string[]>;

constructor() {
    this.filteredStreets = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
}

private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = this._normalizeValue(value);
    return this.streets.filter(street => this._normalizeValue(street).includes(filterValue));
}

private _normalizeValue(value: string): string {
    return value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
}
```

DevTools:
[image]

Comment: Just because you don't see the mat-option inside mat-autocomplete doesn't mean it isn't working.  In the example from your post the options are rendered far from the input and mat-autocomplete element on the DOM towards the bottom of the page inside a cdk-overlay-container.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo for this?